# Splitting or pulling only integers in an array - python

Tags: python

My search skills need improvement, because I couldn't find (or understand) anything that might help me, pull from this array...

```
qtyList = ['[40', '68]', '[18', '10]']
```

I'm trying to pull just the integers and/or place that in a different array so it looks like...

```
qtyList = [40, 68, 18, 10]
```

I thought str_split might work, but I'm pretty sure I'm messing up the syntax.  I tried...

```
array str_split($qtyList, "[")
```

THAT didn't work.

Comment: `$qtyList`? This isn't Python.

Comment: your third line of code is not python...

Comment: Aside: if your `qtyList` is in that form then I suspect a suboptimal choice was made at some point beforehand in an output format, making life more difficult than it needs to be.  If you have control over that side of the code you might want to have another look (CSV, JSON, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: qtyList = ['[40', '68]', '[18', '10]']
```

One way:

```
In [2]: [int(s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')) for s in qtyList]
Out[2]: [40, 68, 18, 10]
```

Another way:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: [int(re.sub('[\[\]]', '', s)) for s in qtyList]
Out[4]: [40, 68, 18, 10]
```

And here's a weird way that works in case that the list always goes on alternating as you show:

```
In [5]: from itertools import cycle

In [6]: slices = cycle((slice(1, None), slice(None, -1)))

In [7]: [int(s[c]) for s, c in zip(qtyList, slices)]
Out[7]: [40, 68, 18, 10]
```

Comment: So did this!  You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

Using a list-comp and regexp is one way:

```
>>> qtyList = ['[40', '68]', '[18', '10]']
>>> import re
>>> [int(re.search('\d+', el).group()) for el in qtyList]
[40, 68, 18, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to go through each list item in a list.

```
for item in qtyList:
    for x in item:
        newList.append(x)
```